# How to I emulate a specific Android device via AVD?

Tags: android, android-emulator

(This question may belong on a different site such as SuperUser. If so, please migrate!)

I'm trying to do a lot of debugging of our web app for Android. The Android emulator seems a tad more difficult for me to get running than the iOS ones. ;)

I have installed the proper Java JDK and Android SDK.

I can now launch AVD manager. This is where I'm stuck. I understand this is where we can customize the specifications of our particular device, but to create a new virtual device, I need to choose a target. However, my target menu is grayed out. I'm guessing there's one more thing I need to install, but I'm lost as to what that is. (BTW, for starters, I'm trying to emulate the Thunderbolt).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing the Android SDK does not install one of the Android platforms to build a AVD from. 
To install a platform do the following:

1. Open the Android SDK Manager (located in the Android SDK directory as tools\android).
2. Select at least one Android platform to install, and click Install Selected. Depending on the version of Android running on the Thunderbolt, you would most likely choose to install Android 2.2 or Android 2.3).
3. Once this installed the target menu will display the version you installed.

Comment: WHen I launch that, it tries to download do download some XML files from google (addons and repository) but fails with URL errors. Hmm...wonder if I have proxy issues...

Comment: In the Android SDK Manager under preferences you may want to place a check in the checkbox for "Force https://...sources to be fetched using http://..." and try the downloads again.

Comment: Yup. Proxy issues. I VPN to a network that isn't set up to handle web proxy connections that well. Going outside the VPN seemed to fix things. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Check this out. You probably missed step 4 
[Installing the SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html)

Comment: My SDK and ADV tools look nothing like the screen shots on that site. I'm guessing I may have an old version. Off to do some hunting...

Comment: It should..What version of eclipse are you using? and i would make sure i have the updated eclipse and follow the instructions on the link i provided to make sure they are done right.

Comment: I'm stumped. I do have the version downloaded from that site. However, I don't have a "SDK and AVD Manager" GUI. Instead of have SDK Manager by itself that, when I launch it, attempts to download some files but fails.

Comment: Ah, so eclipse isn't an optional part of this? That's probably what I'm missing. I'm not really developing--just wanting the emulator for browser testing, but I can set up Eclipse if need be. Off to do that.

Comment: Well it would be much easier using eclipse. Its the way i would do it, and best known to work.

Comment: Thanks, coder_For_Life22. Turns out I was missing the actual specific SDKs since I couldn't get the SDK manager to download them. Turns out it was proxy issues on my end.